# Creating list of objects from a string

Tags: java, arrays, json, mapping

I have a string:

```
[{location=Amsterdam-Nieuwendammerdijk, parameter=no2, date={utc=2020-02-06T18:00:00.000Z, local=2020-02-06T19:00:00+01:00}, value=-999.0, unit=µg/m³, coordinates={latitude=52.3893, longitude=4.94382}, country=NL, city=Amsterdam}, 
{location=Amsterdam-Einsteinweg, parameter=no2, date={utc=2020-02-06T18:00:00.000Z, local=2020-02-06T19:00:00+01:00}, value=-999.0, unit=µg/m³, coordinates={latitude=52.3813, longitude=4.84523}, country=NL, city=Amsterdam}, 
{location=Amsterdam-Van Diemenstraat, parameter=no2, date={utc=2020-02-06T18:00:00.000Z, local=2020-02-06T19:00:00+01:00}, value=-999.0, unit=µg/m³, coordinates={latitude=52.39, longitude=4.88781}, country=NL, city=Amsterdam}]
```

I need to create java objects from this string in a loop and add them to the list. Every object would be  Result class object

```
public class Result{

private String location;
private String parameter;
private String date;
private String value;
private String unit;
private String coordinates;
private String country;
private String city;

public Result() {
}

public Result(String location, String parameter, String date, String value, String unit, String coordinates, String country, String city) {
    this.location = location;
    this.parameter = parameter;
    this.date = date;
    this.value = value;
    this.unit = unit;
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
    this.country = country;
    this.city = city;
}
```

I tried to create JsonArray and then iterate over this array but I got an error:

```
JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) JsonParser.parseString(map.get("results").toString());
```

> Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at
>   line 1 column 80 path $[0].date.utc

I've found many examples using this kind of code but when I try to uses I get an error taht says that I can't use String as a parameter.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

The string I'm trying to convert to array is a value of a key from json:

```
String response = jsonResult(name); //jsonResult(name) - method returning json as a string

Gson gson = new Gson();

Map map = gson.fromJson(response,Map.class);
```

How coud I create objects out of this string?

Comment: The string you've provided is not Json. Json requires "" around String values. You'd need to request an actual JSON String or hand-parse it.

Comment: @Compass Thanks! I didn't notice that